# How to connect circles in react in a tree

Tags: css, reactjs, data-structures

I am a bit new to React and I am working on a project to make a Family Tree. Right now, it is in its initial stages and I have only managed to create a single node (Person Component) of the Tree. How to I connect the nodes based relationships? For ex: if a group of Persons are siblings, then they should be connect like this from their Parents:
[image]

Basically, Married people should be connected horizontally and siblings from the top as seen in the picture above. So far, I have just created the the Person component
(**Person.js**):

```
import React from "react";
import "./Person.css";
function Person(props)
{
    return(
        <div class="person">
           {`${props.firstName}`}
       </div>
    )
}

export default Person;
```

**(Person.css):**

```
.person{
    background-color: #555;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    font: 25px Helvetica, Verdana, Tahoma;
    height: 100px; 
    width: 100px;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center; 
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 25px;
}
```

**(App.js):**

```
import React from 'react'
import Person from './Person'
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App" style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
      <Person firstName = 'Bob' lastName = 'Vance'/>
      <Person firstName = 'Michael' lastName = 'Scott'/>
      <br></br>
      <Person firstName = 'Dwight' lastName = 'Shrute'/>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

I know that this is too broad of a question to answer, and I am not asking for the whole code, I just need some advice to how to approach this and how to make the connections. Also, how to I maintain the tree (should I create a class that maintains the tree structure or some other way?)
Right now, the result is looking like this (hard-coded):
[image]

Comment: awaiting for a feed back, here is the basic CSS idea  https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-lake-0vyjx?file=/src/Person.css

Comment: I see. But there is a bug: for example, if I add more children on the bottom, it connects them horizontally and not the way children should be. and the vertical connection from the parents gets messed up to. The code you send initially is a bit big and I still trying to figure out how to implement it in React.

Comment: yes there is a bug, that's why the comment ;) , you have to deal with this ahead, count your items and pickup only to draw the vertical line ;) ... how do you get the names, i guess you pick them up from a database or json/csv file, and not write them straight into app.js . do you ?

Comment: yes, right now I am hardcoding the names in but eventually, i will get the names from the user and store them in a json file. Could you elaborate on how to fix the vertical line issue? also, and I know this is a big question so just give me some advice, I want the connections for children to come from the top and the connections for spouses to be horizontal. How do you suggest I implement that?

Comment: Not too sure how to advise, maybe this https://codesandbox.io/s/github/vsamaru/json/tree/master/?file=/src/data.json would give you some hints even the folding is not similar